# SSAS Tabular - Deploy without roles from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ssas, tabular

I have one Tabular model (v1400) with multiple project configurations (Dev, QA, PRD). Within the project there is viewer role with users inside - those users should be included only for production deployment.

Is there an option to modify deployment config so I wouldn't have to manually remove/add users depending on current project configuration in Visual Studio?

I know there is this option available in Tabular Editor and was hoping for similar one in VS.

Comment: The Analysis Services Deployment wizard typcially provides more control over the deployment process. Have you look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/deployment/running-the-analysis-services-deployment-wizard?view=asallproducts-allversions